# How can i display the current reading page in a pdf App using Android studio

Tags: android-studio, pdf

I am currently developing a pdf reader app and I want the app to display the current reading page Incase the App is closed and reopened again.
I'm using this dependency
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Kotlin's help, Save your page number in SharedPreferences in `onDestroy()`. When you open your app Then get the page number from SharedPreferences and load pdf.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var defaultPage = 0
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            defaultPage = getPageNumber() // get value form SharedPreferences
            loadPdfViewer()
    
        }
    
    private fun loadPdfViewer() {
            pdfView.fromFile(pdfPath)
                .enableSwipe(true) // allows to block changing pages using swipe
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .defaultPage(defaultPage)
                .enableAntialiasing(true) // improve rendering a little bit on low-res screens
                // spacing between pages in dp. To define spacing color, set view background
                .spacing(5)
                .onError {
                    // do something
                }
                .autoSpacing(false) // add dynamic spacing to fit each page on its own on the screen
                .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH) // mode to fit pages in the view
                .nightMode(false) // toggle night mode
                .load()
    
        }
    
       override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            defaultPage = pdfView.currentPage
            // save this defaultPage number in SharedPreferences
            setPageNumber(defaultPage )
        }

fun getPageNumber(): Int {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("pageNumberPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        return sharedPreferences.getInt("pageNumberValue", 0)
    }

    fun setPageNumber(pageNumber: Int) {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("pageNumberPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        sharedPreferencesEditor.putInt("pageNumberValue", pageNumber)
        sharedPreferencesEditor.apply()
    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share a sample code in java

Comment: @rans if it is helpful, please accept the answer so other people get benefit

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple logic.

Assuming this is an offline or online application. Each time you load a pdf page, you can get the page number each time the user opens a new page or goes back to previous page. You can store this page when the `onDestroy()` or the 'onStop()' method is called.

You can store the page information using:

1. SharedPreferences.
2. Simple SQLite database.
3. Remote database, if the application has remote/online backend.

Each time the `onResume()` method is called, you can fetch the last page information and pass it to the pdf loader or WebView and it will load the page number. In case the page information cannot be retrieved, you can then load the first page of the pdf.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will be more grateful if you share a sample code on the information you shared. That will give me more clarification.